# Parse out Value

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

Anyone any ideas how to parse out this value in the simplest way possible. It needs to be quick and lean. Someone said regex but I haven't used them before. Can they be used to get whats inside the value?

```
name="org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN" value="THIS IS WHAT IS NEEDED"
```

Comment: Take the advise from the person who said; use Regex. It's an appropriate choice for the requirement you are describing.

name=\"(.*?)\"\s*value=\"(?<valueContent>.*?)\" should be close to the regular expression you would need for the line you gave as example. (ps; this is .Net Regex syntax)

Comment: Yes. (I'm sure you'll get many valid answers in mere moments, so I'm just going to encourage you to take the time to learn RegEx -- WELL worth the handful of hours, and useful in just about any language you'll ever use. "Mastering Regular Expressions" is the book you want.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var reVal = new Regex( "name=\"org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN\"\s+value=\"(?<value>.*?)\"" );
string value = reVal.Match( input ).Groups["value"].Value;
```

And I will explain it as well. First we seek for the word `value` with a `"` after it. Then `(?<value>` specifies a named group with the name "value". `.*?\"` means match everything up to the first ". Then we grab the value of the group in the second line.

You could start by reading the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) of the Regex class.

Comment: Thats it? Brilliant! any chance of a link for Regexs?

Comment: I usually keep a copy of "Regular Expression Pocket Reference: Regular Expressions for Perl, Ruby, PHP, Python, C, Java and .NET (Pocket Reference (O'Reilly))" handy. Or I google. I edited my answer with a link to MSDN. But there is tons of regex samples and tutorials out there.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work. I'm sure it just needs some teaking, I will go off and look up whats wrong.

Comment: I forgot the = after value. Added it now. That´s what I get for coding on a mac without VS.

Comment: @ Mikkael Svenson - I worked that out :) I think the issue is the string may contain more than once value. When I try to add in the name part the . (dots) make it go mental, it seems they are special in regex eh?

Comment: . = any character. * = zero or more characters. + = one or more characters. ? = non-greedy. If you have another example of where it fails, that would help. With regex you have to be aware of different inputs, and tune the expression to cover the different scenarios.

Comment: No no it doesn't fail it picks up too well, it finds anything with value="" but I need it to be only the value for the named param above.

Comment: Edited my answer for your scenario. You might want to escape the dots, but they will also match the punctuations ;)

Comment: Cheers buddy! I downloaded a thing called RegBuddy to help me learn these regex, they look deadly!

Comment: Also check out Expresso. They both do the same :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tokenString = "name=\"org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN\" value=\"THIS IS WHAT IS NEEDED\"";

Regex regex = new Regex("value=\"(.*)\"");
var match = regex.Match(tokenString);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
}
```